# How to override CSS class of subnodes?

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a div, so its subnodes can not override my default CSS class.

For example :

```css
.content  { color:red; }
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p style="color:green">Hello</p>
  <p style="color:blue">World !</p>
</div>
```

I would like the text color to be 'red'. The reason is that the content of the div comes from human inputs and I don't want them to modify font, color, size...

I think than "color:red!important;" doesn't work for subnodes.

Comment: Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Then why are you using inline styles.??

Comment: Then why are you using inline styles.??

Comment: You can do it with JS. If you want me to I can expand.

Comment: Is it possible to use class instead of inline style for p tag ?

Comment: @MeteorZero — The OP said it was user input they have no control over.

Comment: @SankarshMakam — The OP said "the content of the div comes from human inputs". They aren't using inline styles. Their users are.

Comment: @Quentin I was intending to use body onload set styling

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Actually, I have no control over html. JS could be a solution, but I would prefer no code is CSS can respond ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think than "color:red!important;" doesn't work of subnodes.

You could write a selector like `.content, .content * { }` … but then the submitted data could override it by using `!important` in the style attribute, so it wouldn't be an effective solution.

---

The only way to do this is to change the style attributes on the paragraphs. This is impossible to do from a stylesheet.

The quick and dirty option would be to use JavaScript to loop over all the elements and remove the styles.

The better approach, since you said:

> the content of the div comes from human inputs and I don't want them to modify font, color, size

… would be to put some proper XSS protection in on your server that would sanitise the external input.

You should use a DOM aware white-listing parser (such as HTML Purifier if your server side code is written in PHP) for this.

Comment: Perfect ! I know that my users can not add "!important" to their classes so I works. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you can use !important to override styles defined in sub-nodes, I have modified your .content class a little, run code snippet to see

```css
.content * { color:red !important; }
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p style="color:green">Hello</p>
  <p style="color:blue">World !</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks :)